# How can I consume an XML webservice?

Tags: jquery

I am using following jQuery ajax method to consume xml based webservice  Please find jquery code as well. But I am unable to grab the data. Similar code works for jsonp but fails with xml. What am I missing?

Update:Local copy works on chrome but not in mozilla.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        var artistURL = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/0/";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            url: artistURL,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("CUSTOMER").each(function () {
                    $(this).find("FIRSTNAME").each(function () {
                            $("#semi").text($(this).text());
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="myButton"> Click Me</button>
<p id="semi"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unable to get xml formatted

Comment: is there multiple `$("#semi")` elements

Comment: The given code should work... unless you can give more details I don't think we can offer much help

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have updated with a public xml

Comment: Is this a cross domain issue or are you able to get the xml document?

Comment: @QueryLars i am able to see xml on my browser. does tht answer  ur query?

Comment: okay, I got that for enabling cors one need jsonp couldn find similar thing for xml any help?

Comment: Unforunately as far as I know there is no XML alternative to JSONP. There are some approaches to store the XML data into a JavaScript object and then use JSONP but that is not very clean.